# Are there any available modern web parts to show existing "Prompted links" or "Picture library" or "Discussion Board" items, inside modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, publishing-page, modern-pages

I am working on a SharePoint online modern site page. and i was able to add a modern web part named "Document library (preview)", as follow:-

[image]

which will then allow me to select an existing docuemnt library, and show the files and folders inside the modern page.

but i was trying to find similar modern web parts to show items from the following lists (which we already have inside our site):-

1. picture library.
2. Prompted links
3. Discussion Board list.

but non of the available web parts will allow us to link them with the above lists.. Here are the modern web parts i am talking about:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please? now i tried adding the "Image" web part and the "Image Gallery" web parts, but both web parts will allow us to select existing images to show. but if we add new images inside the source picture library, the new images will not be shown automatically inside the web part, where we have to manually edit the web part and select the new images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround, we can use **Embed**.

Put the address of your Picture library/Prompted Links list/Discussion Board list into the text box. It will display content from this address.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: but this will also show the whole page components, such as the left side navigation, logo, upper ribbon menu.... so will not be a very user friendly way !!!!!!! embed is nothing but a normal iframe!!! have you try it at your end? did u check how the result will be ..

Comment: No, it will not display the whole page, such as the navigation except the list/library view. I have checked it. I uploaded a screenshot of it for you to refer to. Check my answer.

Comment: yes i re-try the appraoch, and i was able to show the Prompted links + the Pictures inside my Picture library using the Embed approach. also i was able to show the documents using the built-in modern "Document library" web part.. but for the Discussion Board items if i use the embed appraoch the result will show the whole page inside the web part... not sure if i can show the Discussion Board items inside my modern page?? as i did for the prompted links and for the picture library ?

Comment: can you please advice on my above comment?

Comment: It is because the Discussion Board list does not support modern view currently. We can use "?isDlg=1" and iframe. Enter <iframe src="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<sites>/Lists/Discussion01/AllItems.aspx?isDlg=1" width="100%" height="400px"></iframe> in the Embed.

Comment: ok i got your point , so i think the best thing is to use `?isDlg=1` with iframe to show discussion board items inside modern ui

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any such web part available. As a workaround, perform below steps:

Create a document library and put pictures in it - call it Pictures if you like! Add the Picture content type to the Doc lib and make it the default so you can see the digital image metadata. Use the Tiles view to see thumbnails of the images or surface the images in an Image Gallery web part on a page

Comment: and what about the Prompted links & Discussion board? can i use the same process?

Comment: now i did the following steps. i added a new document library, then i add the Image content type, and i set the image content type as defualt CT. then i uploaded some pictures. after that i went to my modern page >> add a new Document library web part >> i chose the new document library >> but the pictures will be show in list view and not in thumbnail view, also the document library does not have a thumbnail view.. now i find a better way to show the pictures from a picture library inside the modern page, is by using the Embed web part, then i enter the url for the `Thumbnails.aspx`